# Timeout in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, timeout

For few weeks now I'm getting this error. I'm using SQL server 2005. I ruled out the network issues, and firewall is not blocking it. Any ideas what may be the cause?

[image]

Comment: There are many things taht coudl casue that but the two I woudl check first are whtehr you have the indexes you need and tehn look at the SQL being sent and see if you can tune it. YOu might ant to buy a big thick book on performance tuning to see all teh other possibilities.

Comment: "you product supplier"? M$ may be many things to people in the computer world, but bad spellers they're generally not. Are you sure this is an popup from SQL server and not the application you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you visit this website.

[kb.iu.edu/data/aytk.html](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aytk.html)

Comment: Link only answers are not reccommended.  You should include at least a brief description about the link you are including, otherwise people may think it's spam.  Please check the http://stackoverflow.com/faq for tips and guidelines.